# jQuery/ ajax file uploader to use in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I need to use some jquery/ ajax file uploader in my asp.net page

Please recommend me some tool or script it is flexible and its resources are also available if required. Requriment is it should be asynchronice and supporting mulitple files.

Comment: http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit - AsyncFileUpload Control

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx

and here is an example of how to use it:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AsyncFileUpload.aspx

Comment: thanks @valipour, but I want soemthing other that tool kit. Because my expeirence is toolkit tools always have limitation and in end one has to decide to leave it.